# Inequality between 1-norm and 2-norm of a vector in

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I have been trying for a while but still can't figure out how to prove this for vectors $x\in\mathbb R^n$:

$$||x||_1 \leq \sqrt{n}||x||_2$$

I can prove the case when it's $\sqrt{n}||x||_\inf$ that's on the right.